# R - difference in last decimal place in different R versions - predict and loess functions

Tags: r

I noticed differences in the last digit of decimal numbers in two different R versions.

I noticed it when using the following code

```
predict(loess(x ~ y, z))
```

The content of my x, y and z variables is the same in both versions. So that can't be the cause.

These are the types of difference that I see. Notice that there's always a difference in the last digit:

```
< 52603 1.94277696545303e-05
> 52603 1.94277696545304e-05

< 52608 2.03530763978453e-05
> 52608 2.03530763978454e-05
```

I have already checked the following things:

- the example code from the loess function R page (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/loess). No differences occur there between the two versions
- .Machine output is the same for both R versions

What could be the cause of this? Or does anybody have suggestions on what to check next to find out the cause of this discrepancy?

These are the sessionInfo() results of my two R versions

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 8 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] optparse_1.6.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1    getopt_1.20.3


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE 12.2 (Mantis) (x86_64)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /nexus/software/R/Rapp/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /nexus/software/R/Rapp/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] optparse_1.6.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 getopt_1.20.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to step and re-examine what floating representation is.  There is a (very famous) article pointed to in the R FAQ under entry 7.31 (which is itself the quite possibly most famous entry in the FAQ) which you can [read from here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

In essence, your numbers are *identical* to the precision of the computer you are on.  We are working with what R calls `numeric` or `double` which (these days) is a 64 bit variable which allows up to 16 digits of precision.

When looking at "equality", the *epsilon* change after which we say "yup, they are equal" is commonly the square root of this---because computation can induce rounding error.

Quick demo:

```
> value <- 1.23456789
> all.equal(value, value + 1e-5)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 8.1e-06"
> all.equal(value, value + 1e-7)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 8.1e-08"
> all.equal(value, value + 1e-9)
[1] TRUE
>
```

So using *what R might use* at the end of, say, a optimisation loop *clearly* labels your values above as equal.  This may seem anything between counter-intuitive to frustrating but such is life with computers.  Do read, and re-read, "7.31" and the reference.

Comment: OK, but how is this related to two different R versions? Because there are no differences when I run the same  function over and over again with the same R version.

Comment: I fear you are still looking at the from "mathematical purity" point of view which is in appropriate.  The numbers are actually "equivalent" and one could say "identical" under standard understanding of what floating-point precision is.  The difference may reflect minute differences in implementation details, in compiler settings, in other code from libraries, and so on.